# Permission denied while creating file in docker container

Tags: java, docker, file, java-io, docker-run

While running a java code in a docker container with root user, getting permission denied error.

Java Code

```
File f = new File("example.xlsx");
f.createNewFile(); // error at this line
```

Error:

```
ava.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1035) ~[na:na]
```

The docker image created with the docker file

```
FROM docker:dind
USER root
RUN apk add curl maven openjdk11
RUN wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.10.0/allure-commandline-2.10.0.zip
RUN unzip allure-commandline-2.10.0.zip -d /
RUN export PATH="${PATH}:/allure-2.10.0/bin"
```

and container created using command

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --add-host="dockerhost:${DOCKERHOST_IP}"
      -e parameter
      --name app ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
```

Comment: The userID under which your program is running does not have write access to the "current directory" of the process.  You should be using absolute paths or explicitly set the current directory to a known good location before attempting to create a file in this way.

Comment: Please share what kind of OS the image is created from. Is it Ubuntu container?  Alpine Linux container? Windows container? MacOS container etc? Can you share a little bit more about how you made this container? I ask because usually this happens to me not bc of my code, but because of something about my container setup. Perhaps I can help with more info.